# How to change data context of Interaction Trigger

Tags: wpf, command, datacontext, interaction

I have a text box A with an interaction trigger. The Data Context of the text box is a property in the view model. However, the ClearCommand in defined in the view Model. How can I change the Data Context of the Interaction Triggers or its Command to the view model it self.

Thank you

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxA"Text="{Binding myObject.TextPrp,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClearCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxB,Path=Text}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind to relative source like this

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxA"Text="{Binding myObject.TextPrp,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourUserControl}, Path=DataContext. ClearCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxB,Path=Text}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```